# Strange behavior with counting spaces and tabs program

Tags: c

C code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () 
{
    int c , nother , new , ndigits [10] , white, tabs ; 

    for ( int i = 0 ; i< 10 ; i++)
        ndigits[i] = 0 ;

    while ( (c = getchar() )!= EOF ) 
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case '0' : case '1' : case '2' : 
            case '3' : case '4' : case '5' : 
            case '6' : case '7' :  case '8' : 
            case '9' : 
                ndigits[c- '0' ]++ ; 
                break ; 

            case ' '  : 
                printf("w");  /*to see how many spaces */
                white++ ; 

            case '\t' :
                printf("t");
                tabs++;

            case '\n' : 
                printf("n");
                new++ ; 
                break ; 

            default : 
                nother++ ; 
                break ;     
        }
    }

    printf ("digits = " ) ; 

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ ) 
        printf ("%d" , ndigits[i]) ;

    printf ( ",tabs = %d , new line = %d,  spaces = %d , other = %d ",
        tabs, white , new , nother ); 

    return 0 ;
}
```

1. When I compile it using `GCC` and just press `Ctrl + z` it prints

   digits = 00000 , tabs = 4200912 , new line = 4194432 , spaces = 2293540
   other  = 2147307520

   where these number come from  ?
2. I compile it again and enter `HELLO HELLO HELLO` and click enter
   and it prints `wtnwtnwnn`

   - why is that (there is 3 n than expected , why it counts three tabs )  ?

Comment: Compile with warnings enabled: `gcc -Wall code.c`

Comment: You initialized `ndigits[i]` to zero. What about `white`, `tab`, etc.?

Comment: yes i forget to initialized other variables :)
but 
 I compile it again and enter HELLO HELLO HELLO and click enter and it prints wtnwtnwnn
why is that (there is 3 n than expected , why it counts three tabs ) ?

Comment: Also missing `break`s?  And you'll be less likely to make such mistakes with a sane coding style (indentation etc).  Go read K&R!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your `case`s are missing `break`s, which doesn't seem to be what you want.

Also you haven't initialized `nother`, `new`, `white`, and `tabs`, but are using them anyway. This results in undefined behavior. (Any decent compiler will give you a warning about this.)

Comment: Indeed `case ' ':` will print `wtn`.

Comment: I edited the above code.its given at the bottom.But it gives output as if expected

Comment: @Downvoter: How is this or any of the other answers "not useful"?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I would have included a statement similar to: *when compiling, always enable all the warnings then fix those warnings (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )

Answer (score 2):

Initialize to zero the counters otherwise their initial value will be unpredictable.

```
int c , nother = 0 , new = 0 , ndigits [10] , white = 0, tabs = 0 ;
```

Also each `case` block (except the ones that catch digits) must be terminated with `break;` to achieve the expected result.

If you omit them the next instructions will be executed.

```
white++;
break;
```

...

```
tabs++;
break;
```

---

Bottom note: you would have found by yourself these mistakes by just enabling warnings on the compiler. Do it: you'll save a lot of time spotting naive errors.

Answer (score 1):

There were several mistakes :

1. you were just declaring the variables and not initializing them.Thus a garbage value was inserted into those variables
2. It was printing 'n' errorneously as you haven't specified the break for the above statement.
3. You were printing no. of spaces as if number of lines ( check it `printf (",tabs = %d , new line = %d,  spaces = %d , other = %d " ,tabs ,white , new, nother) ;` )

the following code generate the output you need :

```
    #include <stdio.h>

     int main () 
       {
    int c=0,nother=0,new=0,ndigits[10],white=0,tabs=0,i=0 ; 
    for ( i = 0 ; i< 10 ; i++)
        ndigits[i] = 0 ;
    while ( (c = getchar() )!= EOF ) 
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case '0' :
            case '1' :
            case '2' : 
            case '3' :
            case '4' :
            case '5' : 
            case '6' :
            case '7' :
            case '8' : 
            case '9' : 
                      ndigits[c- '0' ]++ ; 
                      break ; 
            case ' '  : 
                       printf("w");  /*to see how many spaces */
                       white++ ; 
            case '\t' :
                       printf("t");
                       tabs++;
                       break;
            case '\n' : 
                           {
                        printf("n");
                        new++ ; 
                        break ; 
                             }
            default : 
                      nother++ ; 
                      break ;     
        }
    }
    printf ("digits = " ) ; 
    for (i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ ) 
        printf ("%d" , ndigits[i]) ;
    printf (",tabs = %d , new line = %d,  spaces = %d , other = %d " ,tabs , new,white , nother) ; 
    return 0 ;
      }
```

Comment: check it .it works well.